# Simple access control with WIF 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, wif

What is for sure, the more I read about WIF, the more I get confused about how to do things.
For something that was supposed to ease things, I can't imagine how it would be without. I guess there's too many scenarios and I have hard time to find the one that fits me.

For some (good for my point of view, but maybe bad) reasons, I want to avoid a official STS (`ADFS` or `ACS`) and then write my own to **keep things simple**!

What I'm looking for is being able to deal with Users (that I'll wrap from an AD identity), Groups of users (custom) and Roles that get users/groups assigned to (custom).

I want to decorate my client side methods with the `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` (or a declarative equivalent) to check if the current user has the required role. I want to be able to use that from a Windows Client application or a `WCF` Service hosted on IIS/WAS (Net.tcp is my preferred choice of binding).

Some guidance will be greatly welcome as I'm tired to read on an on `WIF` materials without any improvement of how the solution could be shaped.

Thank you !

Comment: thanks for the edit, but scenario is initially an Italian word, thus the plural is scenarii. ;)

Comment: ADFS tries to do what you are describing. What makes it a bad option in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all - there is no such thing as a simple STS. I hope you realize that an STS is criticial security infrastructure and probably should not be your first WIF project. If you want to have a look at an open source STS to get some ideas have a look here: http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/.

Next authZ happens on the server side (client side is usability). Simply roles checks are rather done with PrincipalPermission. ClaimsPrincipalPermission encourages you to separate service and security code - look up ClaimsAuthorizationManager for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So I can use the thinktecture STS and I'll have to derived from ClaimsAuthorizationManager to create my own, then initialize it at runtime on the server side for the ClaimsPrincipalPermission to work, right?

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate more what should I do? Like I said, I'm pretty lost and it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: As I said - if you want to check for roles only use [PrincipalPermission]. Or read here: http://leastprivilege.com/2011/04/30/what-i-like-about-wifs-claims-based-authorization/